# Exporting a multi-sheet Excel workbook as PDF in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'm using Excel 2007 to build a complex multi-tab (sheet) workbook. I'd like to save this out as PDF from within VBA. I'm trying to use ExportAsFixedFormat.

Sure enough, this call correctly exports a PDF, with the right name in the right place. However, it consists only of the currently visible tab.

I found a thread about this in Excel 2010 (which I assume is similar/same) which placed all of the sheets in an array and then selected them...

Sheet(Array("One", "Two")).Select

However, this returns an error on my machine, that the Select failed.

I'm sure this is something fairly simple, any pointers?

Comment: See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834871%28office.11%29.aspx

Comment: Record a macro - select multiple tabs manually (click on the tabs holding the CTRL key) - stop recording and check the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*sigh* It was something simple.

If you Export ActiveWorkbook instead of ActiveSheet... then you get all the sheets without any Array or Select.